# telegram: instant view button without large preview

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a series of articles on telegra.ph, and I have a Telegram group. I need to pin a menu post in my group with links to my telegra.ph articles, but to allow group members to open the articles using the "instant-view" feature.

Here I face the problem: when I place a telegra.ph link inside the Telegram message, it will be shown with a large preview with big picture which almost takes the whole place on the screen, and in the end there will be the "instant-view" button. But this format is not convenient for menu: I only want the short description of the article and the instant-view button below.

Is there any way to do that? To imitate that somehow?

Comment: You need a bot PM with URL

Comment: Thank you for answer. Could you please explain what is "bot PM" ? I have no idea what is PM here honestly, and google does not helps.

Comment: If it's private message, so what bot should I PM?

Comment: Write your own bot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a **"Instant View"** Button.

Just hyperlink "telegra.ph" with a short sentence(brief description).It will open in "Instant View".

Only thing is that the Telegram should support the site for Instant View the articles.